# UK tourist visa 4.2 (a) and (c)

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, visa-refusal-appeal

I am getting married in 20 days and my fiancé wanted to holiday in the UK after our wedding. His mother is sponsoring the trip as a gift.

I applied along with him and the travel agent asked me to provide my bank statements and ITR and no other supporting documents as I was not the one baring the expense of the trip. My visa along with my partner was refused.

The below was the refusal letter

> • your application
> your immigration history
> The decision
> Converted from Oanda.com on 02.11.2023 - £1 GBP = 101.1176 INR
> • I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraphs) V4.2 of Appendix V: Visitor because:
> • You state that you intend to travel to the UK for 12 days for tourism with your partner. You state that you are employed and your sponsor will be paying for your proposed trip.
> • I have noted the statements made regarding your family circumstances and living arrangements. From the documents and information provided, I am not satisfied that you have any significant personal ties to the country you are applying from that would encourage you to depart the UK.
> • You state that you are self-employed earning yearly income of 600,000 INR = (£5,933.69). You have not demonstrated with the documents you have provided how this income is generated and I am unable to determine from the information provided how you calculated your stated income. It is reasonable that if you are able to provide an income figure then it is demonstrated through the information provided. Furthermore the information you have provided does not demonstrate that you are self-employed. From the information you have provided I am not satisfied that your personal and economic circumstances are as stated.
> • I must take into account your personal and economic circumstances when coming to my decision. It is your responsibility to demonstrate that your personal circumstances are such that if granted leave to enter, you will comply with all of the conditions attached to any such leave and that you will leave the UK on completion of the proposed visit. However, the documents you have provided do not substantiate statements within your application. I am not satisfied you have demonstrated your personal and economic circumstances in the country you are applying from (or elsewhere) offer sufficient incentive to depart the UK.
> • In light of the above, I am not satisfied that you are a genuine visitor and will leave the UK at the end of your visit.
>
> Your application for a visit visa has been refused under paragraph
> V4.2 (a) and (c) of the Immigration Rules.

Should I reapply or that would be a waste of ECO’s time.

Comment: Where did the travel agent come from?

Comment: That agent is just ultra scummy

Comment: Rule #1 when applying for a visa: never rely on a travel agent. There is zero reason to allow anyone else to apply on your behalf, and doubly so if they charge you a fee for the privilege. Look up the requirements for yourself and submit your own application.

Answer (score 4):

You have the option to appeal their decision within a 30-day window, although the chances of a successful appeal are often quite low, and the process can be time-consuming.

Considering your current financial situation, it might be prudent to explore alternative travel destinations. The United Kingdom can be quite expensive, even for those with reasonably high incomes. My wife and I, both of Indian origin and working in Germany, visited the UK for two weeks in July 2023. Despite our combined monthly income exceeding 6000 GBP, we found the UK to be relatively costly. We utilized public transport and chose reasonably priced accommodations, yet we still spent nearly 4000 GBP during our visit, with a significant portion going toward travel accommodations.

In contrast, previous trips to destinations like Greece and Spain allowed us to manage our expenses at nearly half the cost for the same duration. Therefore, I'd recommend considering destinations like Santorini in Greece, where visa processes may be more straightforward.

If you're still determined to obtain a UK visa, it's essential to convey a strong financial position and clearly state your purpose for visiting, such as a honeymoon. Ideally, you should indicate that both you and your wife are willing to cover the trip's expenses. If your combined monthly income exceeds 1 lakh INR, and you're prepared to spend 3 to 4 lakh during your visit, it's possible to reapply for the visa with a higher likelihood of approval.

It's worth noting that compared to other countries, UK visa costs can be relatively high. For instance, a 10-year multiple-entry tourist visa to the USA costs $180, and my parents from India obtained a 5-year Schengen tourist visa for $150 ($75 each). In contrast, the UK requires £771 for a 5-year tourist visa, which can appear expensive. This is something I think UK just commercializing their visa.

I wish you the best of luck with your travel plans.

Comment: Also, if you plan to visit the UK in the summer, that would increase your chances of getting a Visa than in winter.

Comment: Now, it's essential to exercise extra caution because they clearly have doubts about your intentions to return to your home country. They suspect you might become an illegal immigrant. Therefore, for your next visa application, consider applying independently rather than using a travel company. In your cover letter, place a stronger emphasis on your financial commitment, your ties to India, and the importance of returning to India rather than staying in the UK as an illegal immigrant.

Comment: There are no appeals with SVVs

Comment: @Alok Kelsey There is *no* right of appeal for UK Visitor visa refusals, other than on human rights grounds. The OP could go down the judicial review route, however it is difficult to see how that would stand any chance of success - the decision looks 100% correct on the basis of the supporting documentation said to have been submitted (there are 00s of similar questions on TSE). https://immigrationbarrister.co.uk/how-to-challenge-a-visit-visa-refusal-by-judicial-review/